# And the [oscar] goes to Trogdor

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request, clean-up

The [oscar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oscar) tag is for an old and obsolete instant messaging protocol that is no longer used anywhere.

It often gets mixed up with [django-oscar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django-oscar) (I've just gone and cleaned up all incorrectly tagged questions - there were about 20 tagged [oscar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oscar) that were actually meant for [django-oscar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django-oscar)).

There are only 8 questions that are genuinely related to [oscar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oscar), all several years old. Is there any way the tag can be removed to avoid confusion with [django-oscar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django-oscar)?

Comment: 6 of the questions can be closed I think. If enough people agree with that, that only leaves us with 2 questions.

Comment: Maybe make this a [tag:burninate-request] and suggest that [tag:oscar] becomes a synonym for [tag:django-oscar]. Then have a new [tag:oscar-protocol] tag for the old questions?

Comment: @Justastudent: You could make that an answer so we can vote on it.

Comment: What? No Sesame Street jokes?

Comment: @Andrew since no one's answered how we get to Sesame Street yet - it's not likely...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

*All questions previously tagged [oscar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oscar) have been [retagged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oscar-protocol).*

---

As [Chicken](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/247702/chicken) already [pointed out](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/360819/can-we-delete-the-oscar-tag?noredirect=1#comment540956_360819), most of the questions tagged [oscar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oscar) can be closed. This is currently in progress and appears to pull through (4 close votes at the time of writing).

Those (2, it looks like) questions that are left have a legitimate reason to be tagged [oscar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oscar). However, it appears that questioners associate that term with the e-commerce framework for Django instead.

**Proposal.**

1. Introduce [oscar-protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oscar-protocol) (copy wiki from [oscar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oscar)) and tag the ontopic [oscar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oscar) questions with it.
2. Synonimize [oscar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oscar) → [django-oscar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django-oscar) to prevent [oscar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oscar) from popping up again.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! I've created a [new tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/oscar-protocol/info) (edits awaiting review) and retagged the questions.

Comment: With hindsight, I probably should have waited for the close votes to come through...

Comment: @solarissmoke I have edited a notice into my answer in the hopes of getting the final close votes.